# styled-components - Why is global style injected after component styles here?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

consider this example of a react-app using styled-components:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";
import React from "react";

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
    [type="submit"] {
      color: red;
    }
`;

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  color: blue;
`;

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>My Component</h1>
      <button type="submit">regular button</button>
      <StyledButton type="submit">styled button</StyledButton>
    </>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <MyComponent />
    </>
  );
}
```

(See this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-resonance-5569t?file=/src/App.js:123-577))

I'm setting a global style for elements (buttons) with `[type="submit"]` and want to override that style later with a `StyledButton`.

But styled-components seems to inject the global style AFTER the component style or at least prints it that way. If we inspect the `<head>` of the output with browser dev tools, we find:

```
.cshqdf{color:blue;}
[type="submit"]{color:red;}
```

This way, the blue color set by `StyledButton` is overridden by the global style. (The two css selectors have the same priority and therefore rely on order. I specifically used those selectors in my example to make the problem clear.)

**My questions:**

- Why isn't the global style injected before the component styles? I expected this to be the case since `<GlobalStyle/>`is higher in the component tree.
- How can I make sure, my global style is injected before the component style, so it can be overridden more easily?

---

**Note:**
I'm totally aware that there are multiple ways to make `StyledButton` apply it's style while not caring about the order of style injections. One possibility would be of course:

```
const StyledButton = styled.button`
   && {
     color: blue;
   }
`;
```

However, solutions like that is NOT what I'm looking for. I'm trying to understand how to handle styled-component's global style in way such that selectors of equal priority (used for components) are coming afterwards in the style-sheet so I don't need additional tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug:

https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3146

You can look in the github issue for workarounds.